# access image outside the root folder in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("" + metric.Image, UriKind.Absolute);

        ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);

        ImageMetric.Source = imgSource;
```

i have this code

in database im saving the image under path /UploadedImages/greenarrow.png

UploadedImages and my solution  folder is placed in E drive.

But different folders.

how to access it ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the answer

while you are hosting the website in iis ,you can create a images folder in it and save the images from database

so that you can browse the link and find the image.

Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.abc.com"+fieldname.Image , UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
            ImageMetric.Source = imgSource;